# Why is this website sooo slow in IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, performance

I just finished a website: http://www.basenharald.nl and all is good in IE9, chrome and firefox.
It does not support browsers < IE8, but that is planned.

However the website is really really slow in IE8 and for some reason some people encounter that the scrolling divs do not work (not all IE8 users).

Any help on these issues would be greatly appreciated since i cannot locate the problems.

Comment: Try disabling the Javascript (or bits of it) and seeing which bits have an effect. Then, unless you can optimise those bits and unless they are crucial, why not just disable them if the user is running IE8?

Comment: to be fair, it's pretty slow in Firefox 3.6 as well.

Comment: Have you tried using jQueryLint to try and identify potential problems? It may find some unoptimal things you can tweak to try and improve speed. In particular, ensure you are caching the results of selectors in variables so you only run selectors once / when things have changed.

Comment: This almost crashed IE8 for me, but in FF Firebug console I do see this: "ie is null `if (ie[0].match("MSIE")) {` scripts.js (line 1443)"

Comment: Also, sweet website! I'm loving what you've done with Javascript instead of Flash. Very nice!

Comment: IE8 has much slower javascript performance, you can see a chart [here](http://arstechnica.com/microsoft/news/2010/11/internet-explorer-9-platform-preview-7-performance-is-the-priority.ars)

Comment: It is also slow in chrome, i will close the site before loading is done...perhaps you may ajax loading the tabs instead of loading all tabs at once.

Comment: Congrats for finally finishing this page bro

Comment: That is actually a good suggestion. Could you maybe tell me how to do so? I am not really a programmer, more of a designer. Or atleast point me in the right direction?

Comment: @GregL i will check what jQueryLint says later, did not know about this. thanks for all the compliments guys

Comment: See those lines of "$('...').smart3d();"? Try commenting those out. Not sure what they do exactly but it's somewhere to start. For detecting IE8 with Javascript, try: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/giorgio/archive/2009/04/14/how-to-detect-ie8-using-javascript-client-side.aspx

Answer (score 3):

Because IE8 just renders these animations VERY poorly. Also slow PC's will have issues with the animations.

You should detect IE8 (and lower) and disable those effects, because they are not functionally necessary

Comment: Hi douwe, is there any chance you could help me with this? I really do not know how to accomplish this by lack of knowledge

Comment: Look up how to use IE conditional comments to have parts of your page that only get included for the specified versions of IE. Inside those comments, you could include a script tag that sets a class on the `<html>` or `<body>` tags called, say, `browser-ie8`, for example. Then make sure the tag _doesn't_ have that class before enabling certain effects.

Comment: Is there an easy way of detecting a slow PC in JS? Short of running some benchmark test at the beginning or something.

Answer (score 1):

First of all well done on a good looking site. I have used Developer Toolbar in Chrome to detect the following problem. Your site uses or reference  a page called daddy-shoutbox.php. This code in this page or calling code to this page is causing a infinite loop or continues call. From my results I could see that that page takes on aggregate about 500ms to load. 
From the browser perspective I can only assume that IE8 actually shows the symptoms of this loop. My stats showed that the page has made over 130 requests and counting after 2mins.

Comment: You are right about the loop... could you maybe tell me how i can adjust it so it onlyload once and does this again on submit? i have no idea how to do so

Answer (score 1):

Not modern browsers and, as douwe said, even slow PCs will be affected. 
The parallax animation requires lots of CPU time and the effect is mainly related to the aesthetics of the website.

A good compromise between usability and aesthetics could be achieved by reducing the parallax effect.

I suggest you to remove the effect from the text ( class: contentwrapper). It will save you some CPU time and it will give you a more readable text. 
You could even switch to a normal scroll bar. For my experience, customized scrollbars, always give some trouble with the users ;)

If you are happy with the experience on the modern browsers, you could simply discriminate older browsers. 
With jquery you can use [this](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.browser/)

good luck

Comment: Hi Rdpi, excellent suggestion. I am not really a programmer, so if you could help me out with the code i will greatly appreciate it. I understand what it does, i do not understand how i should implement it.

Answer (score 1):

In Opera 11.52 it doesn't load at all..